# Output CosmosDB String

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to call out Connection Strings from the CosmosDB in to KeyVault Secret. I keep getting this error but am unsure what the fix is.

There is nothing online what suggests on how to call out the CosmosDB

The output code is

```
output "connection_strings" {
value = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmos_db.connection_strings
}
```

and on key vault resource is setout as this

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
name = "Tst"
value = module.cosmosDB.connection_strings
key_vault_id = module.kv-secrets.id
}
```

The error that I get in the CLI is module.cosmosDB.connection_strings is list of string with 4 elements

Answer (score 1):

As per [Terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account#connection_strings) connection strings is a list:

> connection_strings - A list of connection strings available for this
> CosmosDB account

If you want to store the connection string into a secret, you should refer to it as:

```
module.cosmosDB.connection_strings[0]
```

Comment: I've tried adding the [0] to the end of the secret value
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
 name         = "Tst"
 value        = module.cosmosDB.connection_strings[0]
I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The way to access the first element of the `connection_strings` array for cosmos in terraform is like so

```
azurerm_cosmosdb_account.foo.connection_strings.0
```

Where `foo` is the local name of the terraform resource you have defined e.g.

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "foo" {
   ...
}
```